# Read Tables from an excel sheet and make them dataframe and merge those dataframes pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple Tables on a single excel sheet.

I want to make a data frame of each table and then merge them.

Each Table has some columns matching and some not matching.

I have tried and could identify table ranges under different group codes but couldn't find any further solution.

Refer attached sheet and

https://1drv.ms/x/s!At2EihO7V0hmujF_VNOrj3xJjZWW?e=Exbvti

I tried the below code

I don't know how to grab convert these identified tables into dataframe and convert them.

Please help me with this

[screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N1vm.jpg)

[groups sheet data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk71q.jpg)

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os



#reading excel files folder

sheets = pd.read_excel(r"D:\PO-1473-Scaff-June22efff.xlsx",header=None)

sheets.dropna(axis=1, how="all" , inplace=True)
sheets.dropna(subset = [2] , inplace=True)

# Set a unique index for each group
sheets["group_id"] = (sheets[0] == "SN").cumsum()
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your dataset ?

Comment: Here you can download the data   

https://1drv.ms/x/s!At2EihO7V0hmujF_VNOrj3xJjZWW?e=Exbvti